# Limiting Access with SFTP Jails

Tags: debian, sftp

I would like to restrict access to only one directory (and his dub directory) for a specific user when he is connected with sftp.

I created the user in apache group:

```
useradd m3dian -g www-data
```

in sshd_config:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User m3dian
    ChrootDirectory /home/www/htdocs/m3dian/html
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I restarted ssh...

But when I try to connect with fileZilla I have the following error: `Connection reset by peer`.

And in ssh logs:

`fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component /home/www`

```
# ls /home -l
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 mai   18  2016 www
```

/home/www is the Apache directory.

Is it possible to configure the rights to keep www-data as owner of /home/www (and the sub directories) and allow m3dian to Chroot to /home/www/htdocs/m3dian/html ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late and you've either found the solution or approached the problem from another direction, but it might help you or someone else.

I have been setting up a chroot SFTP environment and I found this link: [Configure an sftp chroot environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configure-sftp-chroot-environment)
It is based on an AIX system, but I think the statement "*Create a directory to hold all the chrooted users.  This directory must be owned by root and have 700 permissions.  This is a requirement of sftp-server for chrooted users even if there is only one user.*" may be relevant to all implementations of sftp-server.

I had created my user accounts in `/home` which has permissions of `bin:bin`, and I was having the same problem as you described.
Following the link's instructions, I:

- Created a `/sftproot` directory, owned by `root` and in the `system` group, with 755 (u=rwx,go=rx) permissions
- Created a group named `sftpgrp`
- Created subdirectories within `/sftproot` for each user, owned by `root` and in the `sftpgrp` group, with 750 (u=rwx,g=rx,o=) permissions
- Amended my user accounts to change the home location to `/sftproot/<user>`

... and, Hey Presto!, it worked.

Now all I need to do is work out is whether I can get these accounts to access files that are located outside their chroot home directories, this is what happens if you have a wide-open SFTP solution and then later need to lock down some users, but this is for a different post.

I hope this helps.

**Edit with warning**

This did not work when I was testing and we had to abandon this approach, see my SE posting [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1488722/aix-6-1-sftp-allow-chrootd-user-to-access-files-in-location-outside-their-home/1492117#1492117).
It may work on other versions of operating system or openssh, but not on mine, which is AIX 6.1.0.0 and openssh.base version 5.8.0.6101.